# Не могу установить модуль pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

```
PS E:\pythonProject1> pip install pyTelegramBotAPI

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
  return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,

File "e:\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
  exec(code, run_globals)

File "E:\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Answer (score 0):

Все просто, у тебя pip не включен в path
Поищи информацию в интернете, там есть все инструкции или просто переустанови python (удали, потом начни установку заново) и в окне с диалогом поставь галочку
"pip в path" или как-то так там написано
удачи

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Так и надо написать в терминале!